# get value from php tag by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to get images that i fetched from database in my page and show them again in div with id test by ajax i want to show fetched datas again in div with test id when i click on button with addCart class . i think i haveto get value of button that i set it to ids of products in my datbase . and my problem is how can i get id s in ajax code?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addCart").click(function(){
            $.post(".addCart.val()",function(data){
                $("#test").html(data).show();
            });
        });
    });

<div id="test" style="background-color: grey"></div>

   <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($products)):?>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="product-img">
                        <div class="picture">
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="" width="540" height="374" />
                            <div class="img-overlay">
                                <a href="#" class="btn more btn-primary">توضیحات بیشتر</a>
                                <button value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn buy btn-danger addCart">اضافه به سبد خرید</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-titles no-margin">
                        <h4 class="title"><?php echo $row['price'] ?></h4>
                        <!--<h5 class="no-margin">محصول ویژه 434</h5>-->
                    </div>
                    <p class="desc"><?php echo $row['name']?></p>
                    <p class="center-align stars">
                        <span class="icon-star stars-clr"></span>
                        <span class="icon-star stars-clr"></span>
                        <span class="icon-star"></span>
                        <span class="icon-star"></span>
                        <span class="icon-star"></span>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /product -->
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid i want to show fetched datas again in div with test id when i click on button with addCart class

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid has a good point. You are not asking a question. You are simply stating what you want, and showing some code. What in your code does not work the way you wish it to, and how do you want it to work? This question needs elaboration, and the format needs to be a question. Please edit it.

Comment: @Sk use IDs instead of class and also move your js code in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".addCart").click(function(event){
        var id = event.target.val();
    });
```

This will get an value of your button element. But is this id is a valid url to make a ajax call? I dont think so. Please checkout [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) before returning to work on this part of functionality

Comment: so how can i do that?

Comment: @Sk you must pass to $.post method valid url for the first parameter like 'http://your-url.com/images/products/{your_prod_id}'. Then you will be able to manipulate data from server.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are not passing  correct value to php file
please do correction in your code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addCart").click(function(){
         var jq = $(this);
         var cart_id = jq.val(); /* get cart value */
            $.post("ajax.php",{cart_id:cart_id},function(data){
                $("#test").html(data).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

and fetch cart_id in **php** `ajax.php` file like this

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['cart_id'])){
     /* put your code here */
  }
?>
```